# MS sql command automatically run when server activity

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a MS SQL database storing information of members. I wish every day automatic test data today is the birthday of members, then sends congratulatory letter.
So I will use what command? Store Procedure or triger or something else ...? And how to use?

Comment: Make a stored procedure and schedule it to run each work day morning.

Answer (score 1):

You can you the [SQL Server Agent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) service to schedule a job that executes a procedure that finds the correct members and [Database Mail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189635.aspx) to send the mail. The links provided should have the information you need.